# Would it actually be possible to preserve a snow flake?

Tags: water, material-science

In episode one of season 3 of [*The Big Bang Theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory) Leonard offers Penny as a gift a snow flake he says he preserved in some kind of resin, having it brought from the North Pole.

Is this purely artistic license or would it be possible to preserve a snow flake "forever" above 0°C, either with the depicted method or another from what we know today?

Comment: One can possibly preserve the imprint of a snow flake. The snow flake itself is probably not a stable thermodynamic system, so unless it was cooled down to e.g. the temperature of liquid nitrogen in a vacuum it would probably slowly change its shape and crystal structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Hollywood magic, it is a real thing. The image below is a snowflake that was preserved by Tryggvi Emilsson & photographed for use in a 2006 [*Popular Science*](http://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2006-02/save-snowflake-decades) article.

[image]

There's also a [Wiki-How](http://www.wikihow.com/Preserve-Snowflakes) article on preserving them and [Cal Tech](http://www.caltech.edu) also have [similar directions](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/snowcrystals/preserve/preserve.htm) (image above is from this site).

All the sets of directions involve using cold glue on a cold glass slide and then placing the glued snowflakes in a freezer for extended periods of time (the Wiki-How says 48 hours, Cal Tech says one to two weeks, the *PopSci* article gives no timeframe).